# PHP $_SESSION[''] only working on some pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I think I have set everything up right.  But $_SESSION variables load fine on some pages, and not at all on others. The problems only came about when I rearranged the directories to make the URL neater.  Ie /account.php became /account/index.php.  All pages are set to load this code at the start:

```
ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors',8191);
session_set_cookie_params(1800, "./" , "www.example.com", true, true);
session_save_path("/home/users/web/example/writeable-directory/");
session_start();
echo($_SESSION['username']);
```

Most work right, but two pages do not.

When I use the following code, it will echo testï»¿ on all pages.

```
ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors',8191);
session_set_cookie_params(1800, "./" , "www.example.com", true, true);
session_save_path("/home/users/web/example/writeable-directory/");
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = "test";
echo($_SESSION['username']);
```

Comment: In notepad or a different editor, save your PHP file as `UTF-8`. or copy the files that work and move over the code

Comment: @meda Is currently set to 'UTF-8 without BOM' in N++  has only recently started causing problems.  Have recently got SSL and changed directory structure as noted.  Worked fine after I got SSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up needing to change

```
session_set_cookie_params(1800, "/home/users/web/example/unix-directory/" , "www.example.com", true, true);
```

Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `session_start();` before any output to the browser. It's advisable to use `session_start()` as the first line of the file.

If it's still not working there's a possibility you have not set the correct keys.
Check the output of this.

```
<?
session_start();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Please note my answer below

Comment: -1 misleading, the function must simply be called before any output is sent to the browser, it's not that it *must* be the first line.